# Best practice for persisting and incrementing Job Parameters in Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch

Our requirement is to read from a database, marshall the output into XML, and save to a file. Our prototype already does this.

The database SELECT takes a parameter which is a timestamp. Currently, this is stored in a properties file. After each run of the batch, the property file is updated with an incremented date. This is done in a tasklet with runs in a second step.

Is this the correct approach, or is there a better option to store parameters of a job?

Answer (score 1):

you could use the org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersIncrementer interface overriding the only getNext method that allow you to modify appropriately the JobParameters object. You need also to referencing it in the xml using the incrementer="..." attribute on job tag. See paragraph 4.6.4 of the official documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureJob.html

Bye.

sigint76.